# import featuretools and AttributeError: module 'tornado.platform.asyncio' has no attribute 'AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

these are all the packages installed and the environment is Windows 7.1

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py36he6757f0_0
alabaster                 0.7.10           py36hcd07829_0
anaconda                  5.1.0                    py36_2
anaconda-client           1.6.9                    py36_0
anaconda-navigator        1.7.0                    py36_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2            py36hfad2e28_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0
astroid                   1.6.1                    py36_0
astropy                   2.0.3            py36hfa6e2cd_0
attrs                     17.4.0                   py36_0
babel                     2.5.3                    py36_0
backports                 1.0              py36h81696a8_1
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0            py36h79ab834_2
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py36hd4cc5e8_1
bitarray                  0.8.1            py36hfa6e2cd_1
bkcharts                  0.2              py36h7e685f7_0
blaze                     0.11.3           py36h8a29ca5_0
bleach                    2.1.2                    py36_0
bokeh                     0.12.13          py36h047fa9f_0
boto                      2.48.0           py36h1a776d2_1
boto3                     1.9.42                    <pip>
botocore                  1.12.42                   <pip>
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36hd119dfa_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                hbe05fcf_4
ca-certificates           2017.08.26           h94faf87_0
certifi                   2018.1.18                py36_0
cffi                      1.11.4           py36hfa6e2cd_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h420ce6e_1
click                     6.7              py36hec8c647_0
cloudpickle               0.5.2                    py36_1
clyent                    1.2.2            py36hb10d595_1
colorama                  0.3.9            py36h029ae33_0
comtypes                  1.1.4                    py36_0
conda                     4.4.10                   py36_0
conda-build               3.4.1                    py36_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1
conda-verify              2.0.0            py36h065de53_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                h6bb2dd7_3
contextlib2               0.5.5            py36he5d52c0_0
cryptography              2.1.4            py36he1d7878_0
curl                      7.58.0               h7602738_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
cython                    0.27.3           py36h22f4c84_0
cytoolz                   0.9.0            py36hfa6e2cd_0
dask                      0.16.1                   py36_0
dask                      0.20.1                    <pip>
dask-core                 0.16.1                   py36_0
datashape                 0.5.4            py36h5770b85_0
decorator                 4.2.1                    py36_0
distributed               1.20.2                   py36_0
distributed               1.24.1                    <pip>
docutils                  0.14             py36h6012d8f_0
entrypoints               0.2.3            py36hfd66bb0_2
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py36h3d2d736_0
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36hfa6e2cd_2
featuretools              0.4.0                     <pip>
filelock                  2.0.13           py36h20000bf_0
flask                     0.12.2           py36h98b5e8f_0
flask-cors                3.0.3            py36h8a3855d_0
freetype                  2.8                  h51f8f2c_1
future                    0.17.1                    <pip>
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.2.2            py36h342a76c_0
glob2                     0.6              py36hdf76b57_0
greenlet                  0.4.12           py36ha00ad21_0
h5py                      2.7.1            py36he54a1c3_0
hdf5                      1.10.1               h98b8871_1
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2
html5lib                  1.0.1            py36h047fa9f_0
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.6              py36h148d497_1
imageio                   2.2.0            py36had6c2d2_0
imagesize                 0.7.1            py36he29f638_0
intel-openmp              2018.0.0             hd92c6cd_8
ipykernel                 4.8.0                    py36_0
ipython                   6.2.1            py36h9cf0123_1
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h3c5d0ee_0
ipywidgets                7.1.1                    py36_0
isort                     4.2.15           py36h6198cc5_0
itsdangerous              0.24             py36hb6c5a24_1
jdcal                     1.3              py36h64a5255_0
jedi                      0.11.1                   py36_0
jinja2                    2.10             py36h292fed1_0
jmespath                  0.9.3                     <pip>
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36h7636477_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4
jupyter_client            5.2.2                    py36_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36h6d89b47_1
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h56e9d50_0
jupyterlab                0.31.4                   py36_0
jupyterlab_launcher       0.10.2                   py36_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36hd1c21d2_0
libcurl                   7.58.0               h7602738_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libpng                    1.6.34               h79bbb47_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                hd619d38_4
libtiff                   4.0.9                h0f13578_0
libxml2                   2.9.7                h79bbb47_0
libxslt                   1.1.32               hf6f1972_0
llvmlite                  0.21.0           py36he0b0552_0
locket                    0.2.0            py36hfed976d_1
lxml                      4.1.1            py36hef2cd61_1
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
markupsafe                1.0              py36h0e26971_1
matplotlib                2.1.2            py36h016c42a_0
mccabe                    0.6.1            py36hb41005a_1
menuinst                  1.4.11           py36hfa6e2cd_0
mistune                   0.8.3                    py36_0
mkl                       2018.0.1             h2108138_4
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h57e144c_4
mpmath                    1.0.0            py36hacc8adf_2
msgpack                   0.5.6                     <pip>
msgpack-python            0.5.1            py36he980bc4_0
multipledispatch          0.4.9            py36he44c36e_0
navigator-updater         0.1.0            py36h8a7b86b_0
nbconvert                 5.3.1            py36h8dc0fde_0
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h3a5bc1b_0
networkx                  2.1                      py36_0
nltk                      3.2.5            py36h76d52bb_0
nose                      1.3.7            py36h1c3779e_2
notebook                  5.4.0                    py36_0
numba                     0.36.2          np114py36h12cb543_0
numexpr                   2.6.4            py36h30784b8_0
numpy                     1.14.0           py36h4a99626_1
numpydoc                  0.7.0            py36ha25429e_0
odo                       0.5.1            py36h7560279_0
olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0
openpyxl                  2.4.10                   py36_0
openssl                   1.0.2n               h74b6da3_0
packaging                 16.8             py36ha0986f6_1
pandas                    0.23.4                    <pip>
pandas                    0.22.0           py36h6538335_0
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hb2460c7_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36h3ef6317_1
parso                     0.1.1            py36hae3edee_0
partd                     0.3.8            py36hc8e763b_0
path.py                   10.5             py36h2b94a8f_0
pathlib2                  2.3.0            py36h7bfb78b_0
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0
pickleshare               0.7.4            py36h9de030f_0
pillow                    5.0.0            py36h0738816_0
pip                       18.1                      <pip>
pip                       9.0.1            py36h226ae91_4
pkginfo                   1.4.1            py36hb0f9cfa_1
pluggy                    0.6.0            py36hc7daf1e_0
ply                       3.10             py36h1211beb_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36h60b8f86_0
psutil                    5.4.8                     <pip>
psutil                    5.4.3            py36hfa6e2cd_0
py                        1.5.2            py36hbcfbabc_0
pycodestyle               2.3.1            py36h7cc55cd_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h413d8a4_0
pycparser                 2.18             py36hd053e01_1
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36hfa6e2cd_7
pycurl                    7.43.0.1         py36h74b6da3_0
pyflakes                  1.6.0            py36h0b975d6_0
pygments                  2.2.0            py36hb010967_0
pylint                    1.8.2                    py36_0
pyodbc                    4.0.22           py36h6538335_0
pyopenssl                 17.5.0           py36h5b7d817_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36h785a196_1
pyqt                      5.6.0            py36hb5ed885_5
pysocks                   1.6.7            py36h698d350_1
pytables                  3.4.2            py36h71138e3_2
pytest                    3.3.2                    py36_0
python                    3.6.4                h6538335_1
python-dateutil           2.6.1            py36h509ddcb_1
pytz                      2017.3           py36h1d3fa6b_0
pywavelets                0.5.2            py36hc649158_0
pywin32                   222              py36hfa6e2cd_0
pywinpty                  0.5              py36h6538335_1
pyyaml                    3.12             py36h1d1928f_1
pyzmq                     16.0.3           py36he714bf5_0
qt                        5.6.2           vc14h6f8c307_12  [vc14]
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h5aa48f6_0
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36h99a29a9_0
qtpy                      1.3.1            py36hb8717c5_0
requests                  2.18.4           py36h4371aae_1
rope                      0.10.7           py36had63a69_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py36hfa6e2cd_1
s3fs                      0.1.6                     <pip>
s3transfer                0.1.13                    <pip>
scikit-image              0.13.1           py36hfa6e2cd_1
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36h53aea1b_0
scipy                     1.0.0            py36h1260518_0
seaborn                   0.8.1            py36h9b69545_0
send2trash                1.4.2                    py36_0
setuptools                38.4.0                   py36_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36h17d0c80_0
sip                       4.18.1           py36h9c25514_2
six                       1.11.0           py36h4db2310_1
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h763602f_0
sortedcollections         0.5.3            py36hbefa0ab_0
sortedcontainers          1.5.9                    py36_0
sphinx                    1.6.6                    py36_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py36hbbac3d2_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py36hb5e5916_1
spyder                    3.2.6                    py36_0
sqlalchemy                1.2.1            py36hfa6e2cd_0
sqlite                    3.22.0               h9d3ae62_0
statsmodels               0.8.0            py36h6189b4c_0
sympy                     1.1.1            py36h96708e0_0
tblib                     1.3.2            py36h30f5020_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h2698cfe_0
tk                        8.6.7                hcb92d03_3
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0
tornado                   4.5.3                    py36_0
tqdm                      4.28.1                    <pip>
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h096827d_0
typing                    3.6.2            py36hb035bda_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36h6450c06_0
urllib3                   1.22             py36h276f60a_0
vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h3d5aa90_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py36h67c50ae_1
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0
wheel                     0.30.0           py36h6c3ec14_1
widgetsnbextension        3.1.0                    py36_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1            py36he67d7fd_1
win_unicode_console       0.5              py36hcdbd4b5_0
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36he5f5981_0
xlrd                      1.1.0            py36h1cb58dc_1
xlsxwriter                1.0.2            py36hf723b7d_0
xlwings                   0.11.5                   py36_0
xlwt                      1.3.0            py36h1a4751e_0
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zict                      0.1.3            py36h2d8e73e_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h8395fce_2
```

When I imported `featuretools` on jupyter notebook, it raised an error.
Anyone knows how to fix?

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 # Automated feature engineering
>   ----> 2 import featuretools as ft
>
> D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featuretools__init__.py
>   in ()
>         5 from .entityset.api import *
>         6 from . import primitives
>   ----> 7 from .synthesis.api import *
>         8 from .primitives import Feature, list_primitives
>         9 from .computational_backends.api import *
>
> D:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featuretools\synthesis__init__.py
>   in ()
>         1 from **future** import absolute_import
>         2 # flake8: noqa
>   ----> 3 from .api import *
>
> D:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featuretools\synthesis\api.py in
>   ()
>         3 # flake8: noqa
>         4 from .deep_feature_synthesis import DeepFeatureSynthesis
>   ----> 5 from .dfs import dfs
>         6 from .encode_features import encode_features
>
> D:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featuretools\synthesis\dfs.py in
>   ()
>         3 from .deep_feature_synthesis import DeepFeatureSynthesis
>         4 
>   ----> 5 from featuretools.computational_backends import calculate_feature_matrix
>         6 from featuretools.entityset import EntitySet
>         7
>
> D:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featuretools\computational_backends__init__.py
>   in ()
>         1 # flake8: noqa
>   ----> 2 from .api import *
>
> D:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featuretools\computational_backends\api.py
>   in ()
>         1 # flake8: noqa
>   ----> 2 from .calculate_feature_matrix import (
>         3     approximate_features,
>         4     calculate_feature_matrix
>         5 )
>
> D:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featuretools\computational_backends\calculate_feature_matrix.py
>   in ()
>        15 
>        16 from .pandas_backend import PandasBackend
>   ---> 17 from .utils import (
>        18     bin_cutoff_times,
>        19     calc_num_per_chunk,
>
> D:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featuretools\computational_backends\utils.py
>   in ()
>         8 import pandas as pd
>         9 import psutil
>   ---> 10 from distributed import Client, LocalCluster
>        11 from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
>        12
>
> D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed__init__.py
>   in ()
>         3 from . import config
>         4 from dask.config import config
>   ----> 5 from .actor import Actor, ActorFuture
>         6 from .core import connect, rpc
>         7 from .deploy import LocalCluster, Adaptive
>
> D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\actor.py in
>   ()
>         2 import functools
>         3 
>   ----> 4 from .client import Future, default_client
>         5 from .compatibility import get_thread_identity, Queue
>         6 from .protocol import to_serialize
>
> D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in
>   ()
>        42 from tornado.queues import Queue
>        43 
>   ---> 44 from .batched import BatchedSend
>        45 from .utils_comm import (WrappedKey, unpack_remotedata, pack_data,
>        46                          scatter_to_workers, gather_from_workers)
>
> D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\batched.py in
>   ()
>         8 from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
>         9 
>   ---> 10 from .core import CommClosedError
>        11 from .utils import parse_timedelta
>        12
>
> D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py in
>   ()
>        18 
>        19 from .compatibility import get_thread_identity
>   ---> 20 from .comm import (connect, listen, CommClosedError,
>        21                    normalize_address,
>        22                    unparse_host_port, get_address_host_port)
>
> D:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm__init__.py in
>   ()
>         7                          get_local_address_for,
>         8                          )
>   ----> 9 from .core import connect, listen, Comm, CommClosedError
>        10 
>        11
>
> D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\core.py
>   in ()
>        10 
>        11 from ..metrics import time
>   ---> 12 from ..utils import parse_timedelta
>        13 from . import registry
>        14 from .addressing import parse_address
>
> D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\utils.py in
>   ()    1388         import asyncio    1389         import
>   tornado.platform.asyncio
>   -> 1390         asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(tornado.platform.asyncio.AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy())
>   1391     1392
>
> AttributeError: module 'tornado.platform.asyncio' has no attribute
>   'AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same issue.
I not find class 'AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy' in tornado/platform/asyncio.py of tornado's version '4.5.1', but in source code tornado master of github.
so you can install the newest tornado.

Now, pip can not install tornado-5.1.1
you can follow steps:
1: download [tornado-5.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/tornado/#files) 
2: pip install *.whl  or cd file_dir python setup.py install

Comment: Conda can install tornado-5.1.1, FWIW.